# Variables and HTML HREF

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a question about an edit button and a MySQLi variable.

This is what i have:

Now i want the "edit" tekst to be redirected to a page, and this page is an overview of the reparation. So every "edit" needs to point to different details.
But what kind of HREF do i need? This is my code from the table:

```
$query = "SELECT reparatieid, klantid, model, merk, framenummer, verzekerd, garantie, gereed from reparatie ";
        $result = $link->query($query);


        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                print("<table border= 1px >");
                print("<tr>");

                print("<td class=tdrp>"     .    $row ["reparatieid"] . "</td>" . " ");
                print("<td class=TDID>"     .    $row ["klantid"] .     "</td>" . " ");
                print("<td class=tdmodel>"  .    $row ["model"] .       "</td>" . " ");
                print("<td class=tdmerk>"   .    $row ["merk"] .        "</td>" . " ");
                print("<td class=tdfrm>"    .    $row ["framenummer"] . "</td>" . " ");
                print("<td class=tdverz>"   .    $row ["verzekerd"] .   "</td>" . " ");
                print("<td class=tdgara>"   .    $row ["garantie"] .    "</td>" . " ");
                print("<td class=tdgereed>" .    $row ["gereed"] .      "</td>" . " ");
                echo  '<td class=tdbewerk><a href="/reparatiebewerk.php?reparatieid=$_GET["reparatieid"]">Edit </a> </td>';

                print("</tr>");
```

So, the last echo is the "edit" button, and this line of href:

```
/reparatiebewerk.php?reparatieid=$_GET["reparatieid"]
```

But it does not work! Do you know what the problem is? When i do this in my browser, it points to the good page, so i only need to have the href voor the EDIT text,

```
http://127.0.0.1/reparatiebewerk.php?reparatieid=547c97bfe3a2c
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Doesn't the link need to include something from the `$row`, so it knows which item you want to edit? You'll have the same `Edit` link on every row of the table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should be the correct statement :

`echo  "<td class=tdbewerk><a href='/reparatiebewerk.php?reparatieid=" . $row['reparatieid'] . "'>Edit </a> </td>";`

Answer (score 2):

**Use double quotation "xxx" when you need to detect $variable.**
Use single quotation 'xxx' will output $variable as normal text.

In your case,

```
echo  '<td class=tdbewerk><a href="/reparatiebewerk.php?reparatieid=$_GET["reparatieid"]">Edit </a> </td>';
```

should be

```
echo  "<td class=tdbewerk><a href='/reparatiebewerk.php?reparatieid=$_GET[reparatieid]'>Edit </a> </td>";
```

This should work!

Answer (score 0):

At first you can try to replace your echo with:

```
echo  '<td class=tdbewerk><a href="/reparatiebewerk.php?reparatieid=' . $_GET['reparatieid'] . '">Edit </a> </td>';
```

And in your `reparatiebewerk.php` file read value from url with:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET["reparatieid"];
// Do whatever you need with your id
```

Comment: `reparatieid` he is getting the value from the query, not a form, you shouldn't use get in this case.

Comment: He is getting value from url, so $_GET is valid.